# How to properly get the body of a WebTarget get request response (JAX-RS)?

Tags: java, json, web-services, intellij-idea, jax-rs

How do i get the body of a HTTP get request with the **javax.ws.rs** library?

***I tried:***

```
Response response = service.path(path).request().get();
String body = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

but that doesn't work. Instead i get this exception: **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/NoContentException`**

***Then i tried:***

```
Response response = service.path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get();
String body = response.readEntity(JSONObject.class);
```

because I should actually get a JSON String back but i don't need it as JSON Object, that's the reason why i tried it like above before.

But that doesn't work at all, i even can't compile and get the (IntelliJ) message 
`no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that JSONObject conforms to String inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: JSONObject upper bounds: Object, String`

***Addition:***

I get 200 as response status so everything worked fine and when i do the same in e.g. Postman or Fiddler it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Jackson: first you create object from body

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream responseBody = response.getBody().in();
JSONObject jsonobject = mapper.readValue(responseBody, JSONObject.class);
```

Then transform jsonobject to string:

```
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonobject);
```

Comment: I don't wan't to use another library just for that, and the method `getBody()` doesn't even exist.

Comment: yes it doesn't exist, it's a function of retrofit library.
you can try  Response.readEntity(InputStream.class) to get body inputstream.
To transform to string I don't have other solution without using external library, Jackson is awesome and so useful for doing such things related to json.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case it should also work with

```
Response response = service.path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get();
```

String body = response.readEntity(String.class);

because it tries to read the Entity and construct an object of the given type out of it. So I think that should work.